# EMR 6.x cross-account access to Glue catalog

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-emr

We're using SparkSQL on EMR version 6.2.0. To run the SparkSQL scripts, we're using Zeppelin notebooks on the EMR. We've been required to access Glue catalog cross-account (both read and write).
I didn't find any way to do that with EMR version 6.x

A lot of sources are pointing to [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/query-glue-data-catalog-cross-account/) but it doesn't support version 6.x. Same thing for AWS Lake formation.

Would appreciate any help in achieving this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and this is working from EMR version 6.3.0, but the documentation doesn't say so